# How to enable REST api calling into Tensorflow's Syntaxnet

Tags: python, rest, tensorflow, syntaxnet, serving

I have installed Tensorflow on Ubuntu linux machine. Followed the following link to install syntax net.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet

Successfully able to parse a sentence using Syntaxnet using following command.
`echo 'Bob brought the pizza to Alice.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh`

I want to run Syntaxnet's Parsey McParseface parser using REST from AWS AMI image.

Followed instructions given in this post to enable Tensorflow serving.
https://github.com/dmansfield/parsey-mcparseface-api

Received following errors when I ran the command " bazel build -c opt parsey_api/..."

ERROR: Failed to load Skylark extension '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl'.
It usually happens when the repository is not defined prior to being used.
Maybe repository 'io_bazel_rules_closure' was defined later in your WORKSPACE file?
ERROR: cycles detected during target parsing.

How can I get past this to actually use Tensorflow serving the model?

Any help is greatly appreciated.